# How can I modify the Serializer filed of django restframework ModelSerializer when use it in view.py?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my DRF serializer:

```
class TranMetaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = TranMeta
    fields = "__all__"
```

And when i use the serializer in view.py, i want to change the filed via request.get filed:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def getTran_all(request, formar=None):
    fields = request.GET.get("fields")
    if fields:
        fields = fields.split(",")
        data = TranMeta.objects.order_by("data_id").values(*fields)
    else:
        fields = "__all__"
        data = TranMeta.objects.all()
    serializer = TranMetaSerializer(data, many=True, fields=fields)
```

But the code above raise an error which says "Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'"
So what can i do to achieve my goal?

Comment: what are the possible values for fields? what will be the input and expected output?

Comment: @Zilay The values of the fileds is just the models fileds, in fact, i just want to specify the serializers filed in views function, not in Serializer class, because sometimes i'm not sure which filed should be serialized before i use it in views. And sometimes i will use a serializers class in many views function, so i beleieve it is better to specify the fields respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a dynamic fields serializer available in [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields)

```
class TranMetaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = TranMeta
    fields = "__all__"

  def __init__(self, *args, ***kwargs):
    # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
    fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

    # Instantiate the superclass normally
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if fields is not None:
        # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
        allowed = set(fields)
        existing = set(self.fields)
        for field_name in existing - allowed:
            self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. This excellent solution is beyond the reach of AI.